# Are there any examples of Android Auto Integration in Flutter Mobile app?

Tags: android, flutter, android-auto, carplay

We have a working flutter app that works with Google map and is useful while driving. We are looking to build Android-Auto/CarPlay integration. We found a decent project Flutter_carplay (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carplay) that can make it easier the integration of CarPlay in our app. However, I haven't yet found a similar project for Android Auto Integration. There are two ways, I am thinking about this:

1. Flutter supports running native code. So, we can build the Android Auto screens in Kotlin/Java and run them from flutter app. This can get a little time-consuming.
2. Are there any projects similar to flutter_carplay that can make this task easier?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This [github thread](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26801) may help you